# Applying a 'mean filter'

Tags: c#, image

I am just trying to apply a "mean filter" with C#. The working code below gets window size (3,5,7,9,...) from `textBoxWinSize` and applies the mean filter.

I am new and I want your comments and suggestions about my code so I can improve myself.

Can I make it faster? How? Is there any unnecessary or absurd part in the code? Can it be improved in any other way?

I do not care about border pixels for now.

```
private void buttonApplyFilter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int R, G, B,aveR,aveG,aveB;
    double sumR,sumG,sumB;
    Color pixel_value;
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(bmpOrig);
    int WinSize = Int32.Parse(textBoxWinSize.Text);
    int col,row,n,m;
    for (col = (WinSize-1); col < (bmp.Width-WinSize); col++)
        for (row = (WinSize-1); row < (bmp.Height-WinSize); row++)
        {
            sumB = 0;
            sumG = 0;
            sumR = 0;
            for (m=-(WinSize-1)/2; m<=(WinSize-1)/2;m++)
                for (n=-(WinSize-1)/2;n<=(WinSize-1)/2;n++)
                {
                    pixel_value = bmp.GetPixel(col+m, row+n);
                    R = (pixel_value.R);
                    G =(pixel_value.G);
                    B = (pixel_value.B);
                    sumR = sumR + R;
                    sumG = sumG + G;
                    sumB = sumB + B;
                }
            aveR = (int)(sumR / (WinSize * WinSize));
            aveG = (int)( sumG / (WinSize * WinSize)); 
            aveB = (int)( sumB / (WinSize * WinSize));
            bmp.SetPixel(col, row, Color.FromArgb(aveR, aveG, aveB));
        }
    pictureBox1.Image = bmp;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First up, I think you're doing too much in the button click handler. The logic for applying the mean filter should be moved to its own method, something like

```
private static Bitmap ApplyMeanFilter(Bitmap input, int windowSize)
```

Now it can be re-used and unit tested more easily.

---

I think this line is wrong

> ```
> pixel_value = bmp.GetPixel(col+m, row+n)
> ```

in that `bmp` should be `bmpOrig`. The reasoning is that you're changing pixels in `bmp` as you go, which will have an effect on pixels that are processed later. That is, they won't be assigned the mean of their original surrounding pixels.

---

Assuming the `bmp` should be `bmpOrig`, we can optimise this quite a bit.

Say that instead of a bitmap, we have a 2D array of ints.

**input**

\begin{array}{c | c c c c}
  & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & -1 \\
1 & 4 & 1 & 6 & -3 \\
2 & 4 & 5 & 9 & -3 \\
3 & 4 & -2 & 6 & -3 
\end{array}

We can compute another 2D array such that the \$(i, j)\$-th entry is the sum of entries in the submatrix \$(0, 0), (i, j)\$:

```
var sums = new int[height, width];
for (var i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    var sum = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        sum += input[i, j];
        sums[i, j] = i > 0 ? sums[i - 1, j] + sum : sum;
    }
}
```

**sums**

\begin{array}{c | c c c c}
  & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
0 & 1 & 3 & 6 & 5 \\
1 & 5 & 8 & 17 & 13 \\
2 & 9 & 17 & 35 & 28 \\
3 & 13 & 19 & 43 & 33 
\end{array}

Now suppose we want to find the sum of the values in the 3x3 square around entry \$(i, j) = (2, 2)\$:

\begin{array}{c | c c c c}
  & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & -1 \\
1 & 4 & 1 & 6 & -3 \\
2 & 4 & 5 & \textbf{9} & -3 \\
3 & 4 & -2 & 6 & -3 
\end{array}

We can do this quickly using the matrix we just computed. The answer is given by

```
  sums[3, 3] - sums[3, 0] - sums[0, 3] + sums[0, 0]
= 33 - 13 - 5 + 1
= 16
```

In general, if `halfWindow = (windowSize - 1) / 2` then the sum of values in the `windowSize * windowSize` square around entry \$(i, j)\$ is given by

```
sums[i + halfWindow,     j + halfWindow] -
sums[i - halfWindow - 1, j + halfWindow] -
sums[i + halfWindow,     j - halfWindow - 1] +
sums[i - halfWindow - 1, j - halfWindow - 1]
```

The beauty is, computing the sum of the surrounding `windowSize * windowSize` values this way is independent of `windowSize`.

---

Getting back to the original problem of bitmaps, let's suppose we have a struct that will let us sum up the RGB values of the pixels. I named it `Clr` because I'm not very imaginative today; I'm sure you can think of a better name. Let's also assume we have operators `+`, `-` and `/` defined in the obvious way.

Putting it all together would look something like this

```
var sums = new Clr[input.Height, input.Width];
for (var i = 0; i < input.Height; i++)
{
    var sum = new Clr();
    for (var j = 0; j < input.Width; j++)
    {
        sum += Clr.FromColor(input.GetPixel(j, i));
        sums[i, j] = i > 0 ? sums[i - 1, j] + sum : sum;
    }
}

var output = new Bitmap(input);
var windowArea = windowSize * windowSize;
var halfWindow = (windowSize - 1) / 2;
for (var i = windowSize - 1; i < input.Height - windowSize; i++)
{
    for (var j = windowSize - 1; j < input.Width - windowSize; j++)
    {
        var clr = sums[i + halfWindow,     j + halfWindow] -
                  sums[i - halfWindow - 1, j + halfWindow] -
                  sums[i + halfWindow,     j - halfWindow - 1] +
                  sums[i - halfWindow - 1, j - halfWindow - 1];

        output.SetPixel(j, i, (clr / windowArea).ToColor());
    }
}

return output;
```

Running this on a 256x256 image, I got the following timings

```
windowSize       this               original
 3          00:00:00.0910750    00:00:00.4720078
 5          00:00:00.0899366    00:00:01.2674758
 7          00:00:00.0853111    00:00:02.2569419
 9          00:00:00.0938911    00:00:03.4408123
11          00:00:00.0840854    00:00:04.9614386
```

---

Other things to try that might improve performance:

- Use a `Clr[][]` instead of a `Clr[,]`. See [Why are multi-dimensional
  arrays in .NET slower than normal
  arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/468873/1220238)
- Doing the above will let you move `sums[i + halfWindow]` and `sums[i - halfWindow - 1]` into variables outside the inner loop.
- Compute the first row of `sums` separately to remove the conditional in this line `sums[i, j] = i > 0 ? sums[i - 1, j] + sum : sum;`

Comment: How can I create the struct Clr includes RGB?

Comment: @sigara I've uploaded an example [here](http://share.linqpad.net/osquvk.linq) (you'll need [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) to run it, but it can be read with any text editor).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not going to try optimizing this. Right now, this code is ugly for other reasons. First and foremost being the naming: In C#, local variables should be `camelCase` and should generally not include abbreviations. Abrvs dt mk tns esy t ndrstd. They do not make things more performant.

Next, this is C#. Defining all your variables at the top is not going to affect performance. It is generally a good idea to define variables at the scope they belong so as to avoid confusing people.

Next, `m` and `n` are very unusual loop variables. Generally, you start with `i` and `j` for those, because no one expects `i` to mean anything else.

I've attached the end result, which is much cleaner, easier to understand code.

It may also be beneficial to create two variables for `windowSize`, since you use it in more than one place using identical formulas. Those are a better idea than copying it everywhere it's needed.

Hopefully a later review will cover other concerns.

```
private void ApplyFilterClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var bitmap = new Bitmap(original);
    var windowSize = Int32.Parse(textBoxWinSize.Text);
    for (int column = (windowSize - 1); column < (bitmap.Width - windowSize); column++)
    {
        for (int = (windowSize - 1); row < (bitmap.Height - windowSize); row++)
        {
            double sumBlue = 0;
            double sumGreen = 0;
            double sumRed = 0;
            for (int i =- (windowSize - 1)/2; i <= (windowSize - 1)/2; i++)
            {
                for (int j =- (windowSize - 1)/2; j <= (windowSize - 1)/2; j++)
                {
                    var pixelValue = bitmap.GetPixel(column + i, row + j);
                    var red = pixelValue.R;
                    var green = pixelValue.G;
                    var blue = pixelValue.B;
                    sumRed = sumRed + red;
                    sumGreen = sumGreen + green;
                    sumBlue = sumBlue + blue;
                }
            }
            var averageRed = (int)(sumRed / (windowSize * windowSize));
            var averageGreen = (int)(sumGreen / (windowSize * windowSize)); 
            var averageBlue = (int)(sumBlue / (windowSize * windowSize));
            bitmap.SetPixel(column, row, Color.FromArgb(averageRed, averageGreen, averageBlue));
        }
    }
    pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
}
```